# Add Selected in Dropdown Option in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to add "selected" on the dropdown option in Laravel?

I am doing editing profile. In the profile I have a dropdown list, the options are pulled from database, like this.

//Controller

```
$gender= Gender::lists('gender', 'id');
```

//View

```
{{ Form::select('gender', $gender, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

//Output

```
<select class="form-control" name="gender"><option value="1">Male</option><option value="2">Female</option></select>
```

My question: If the user is female, how to add "selected" in the female option if the user has saved female in database before, so that I can show the gender when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default value at the 3rd parameter.

Assume `Female id` is `2`

```
{{ Form::select('gender', $gender, 2, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

If you already has a `$user` with `sex_id attribute`(or your sex column), You can pass it to the `Form::select` as well.

```
{{ Form::select('gender', $gender, $user->sex_id, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists